# React-router different path same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this particular use case and I cannot find any solution.
I need to use the **same component** for **different paths**, unfortunately the paths have different lengths like described in the pattern below

```
/targetpath/:targetpathId
/somepath/:somepathId/targetpath/:targetpathId
/somepath/:somepathId/someotherpath/:someotherpathId/targetpath/:targetpathId
```

I don't want to write each route for each case because it does not scale...
So I am trying to write the path dynamically in this way

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={`${match.url}/targetpath/:targetpathId`}
    component={Photo}
  />
  //Other routes...
</Switch>
```

But because the routes have variable lengths this does not work every time

I am trying with Regex but still no luck

Anyone that has encountered this problem?

Comment: to be honest, that just sounds like a really bad routing design. It's a bit too convoluted. Can you share what features you are trying to integrate with this sort of nested paths.

Comment: ``^.*targetpath\/:targetpathId.*$``
https://regex101.com/r/ef3pem/1

Comment: Does it work for you? `arrayOfPatterns.map(pattern => <Route path={pattern} component={Photo} key={pattern} />)`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I am start thinking you are right and I should definitely change the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved like this, thanks to Drusto

```
path="(^.*)/targetpath/:targetpath"
```

But in general Christopher Ngo was right that is a bad routing design and therefore I have decided to get another approach

Answer (score 0):

It seems unwise to create routes in the this manner. You can simply define a different route that loads the same component.

```
<Route to='/path1' component={MyComponent} />
<Route to='/path2' component={MyComponent} />
```

Yes, it's a pain having to write each component out, but it's far more intuitive, and you're less likely to implement a bug.

Comment: As I said, in my case that approach is not an option